# Update SQL record only if select does not return null

Tags: sql, select, sql-update

I have a SQL table of customers and their parent customers where I need to update the customer table to show the customers owner (which is another entry in the customer table). i.e a Customer may exist in their own right or they may (optionally) have a parent record in the same table. I have tried using the SQL command

```
Update 
  Customers
SET
  Customers.Owner = (SELECT TOP 1 Owner from Customers Customer where CustomerId = Customers.Parent)
```

but this sets the owner to null if there is no parent. How do I only update the record if the Select statement does not return null. I tried adding  a where clause but that only seems to act on the select clause, not on its result.

Answer (score 3):

You may use EXIST:

```
Update 
  Customers
SET
  Customers.Owner = (SELECT TOP 1 Owner from Customers Customer 
                     where CustomerId = Customers.Parent)
WHERE EXIST (SELECT TOP 1 Owner from Customers Customer 
             where CustomerId = Customers.Parent)
```

Comment: `TOP 1` is not needed inside the `EXISTS`, but will work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MERGE` statement as well.

```
MERGE INTO Customers tgt
USING Customers src
ON (src.CustomerId = tgt.Parent)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE tgt.Owner = src.Owner;
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.